# MongoDB update has a bug?

Tags: mongodb

When I tried to use update() to modify a MongoDB document, I found some strange things as below:

```
t.find()

t.insert({f1:"aaaa",f2:"bbbb"})

t.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5322b875ee8d53ebb10c48c7"), "f1" : "aaaa", "f2" : "bbbb" }

t.update({f1:"dddd"},{f2:"bbb6",f1:"dddd"},true)

t.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5322b875ee8d53ebb10c48c7"), "f1" : "aaaa", "f2" : "bbbb" }

{ "f2" : "bbb6", "f1" : "dddd" }

t.update({f1:"cccc"},{f2:"bbb6",f1:"cccc"},true)

E11000 duplicate key error index: local.test.$_id_  dup key: { : null }
```

So, my question is why MongoDB create a document without a `_id`? And more, when I did it again, why did it fail?

Is it a bug since in MongoDB document, it is ensured that every document has a unique `_id` field?

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Your update statement is should be like this 
t.update({f1:"dddd"},{$set : {f2:"bbb6",f1:"dddd"}},true)

Comment: change update statement like  `t.update({f1:"dddd"},{$set : {f2:"bbb6",f1:"dddd"}},{upsert:true})`. `upsert` will add the document with unique id, if query doesn't match your criteria.

Comment: Hi, Devesh, same result: > t.update({f1:"eeee"},{$set:{f2:"bbb8",f1:"aaaa"}},true)
> t.find()
> { "f1" : "aaaa", "f2" : "bbb8" }
>

Comment: What kind of collection is this? I know of no way that a normal collection can have no _id unless you set a deprecated setting that can actually remove it

Comment: OK, I think it is a bug only in mongodb windows version. I retested it on mongodb 2.4.6@linux and didn't see this issue.

Comment: Hmm the two should be compiled from the same source so the only thing I can think of is settings, how exactly do you run Windows mongod and also how did you create the database and the collection?